# Cauchy Riemann equations for $\frac{x^3(1+i)-y^3(1-i)}{x^2+y^2}$ at 0

Tags: complex-analysis

The function is defined to be zero at z =0. I found $u_x$ to be 0/0 at z=0, same for , $u_y$. What do we do when that happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since$$u(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}&\text{ if }(x,y)\neq/0,0)\\0&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$then$$u_x(0,0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{u(x,0)}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^3}{x^3}=1.$$

Comment: Can you please edit your answer? I also have to prove that its continuous at 0. However, I can't seem to express this function in terms of z. If I express it in terms of x and y, then I'll have to choose the way of approaching 0.

Comment: That is a different question. Pease post it as such.

Comment: But it's almost the same thing. Should I just write it in an edit?

Comment: If you do that, then I will answer it.

Comment: I posted it : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047287/continuity-of-fracx31i-y31-ix2y2-at-0